# How do I link to an answer?

Tags: support

I know someone must have asked this already, but I can't find it. How do I get a link to a specific answer on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 14):

There's a "Share" button at the bottom left of every Q/A:

> [image]

Comment: Geez, yup, just found that staring me right in the face. I can't believe I looked right past that all this time. Thanks.

Comment: I see red circle, I upvote.

Comment: @Maroun even non hand drawn ones? Heretic!

Comment: @Patrice I don't consider a non-hand drawn circle a circle.

Answer (score 6):

Every question and answer has a Share button in the bottom left which gives you a link; in this case it gives you:

[How do I link to an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327015/5815149)

Which will automatically appear to you as the question, rather than the link I actually wrote into this post.

[image: Share Buttons]

Comment: No red freehand circles: -1

Comment: So sorry; my mistake

Comment: That's infinitely better now!

Comment: @Cerbrus I live and learn